# Angular.js - share the same model between multiple views by $rootScope

Tags: angularjs

In an Angular.js app, I have a page with multiple inputs.
There are multiple views (each of them render a small number of inputs) but only one Save button.

When the user want to save I need to collect all the changes and send them to the client.

The way I chose to implement it is by loading the initial content in the `ng-app` main controller, and in each view I use `$rootScope` as the data container (instead of `$scope`).
This way I can access all the binded data from the parent controller to send it to the server.

Is it legal?
Is there a nicer way implement it?

Comment: please can you post a sample code to analyse?

Comment: Probably not the best way to do it. As referenced by  @pkozlowski.opensource you should really leave the $rootScope alone and use a service.